# Resolve svn status S – find where an erroneous svn:externals property is defined

Tags: svn, version-control, svn-externals

**How I got here**

After painstakingly merging 2 divergent folders of what should have been the same codebase (which different people were working on in different locations), I attempted to consolidate the codebase seamlessly by setting one of these folders as the `svn:external` of the other.

This didn't work, because externals can't be in the same repo as their links. I *think* I ran `svn cleanup` after discovering this the hard way in an attempt to resolve the errors svn was producing (nothing is locked, which would seem to indicate I did).

**What I want**

In establishing this I lost track of where the `svn:externals` property was set: the folder has a `svn status` of `S` (which indicates that its contents are in a different repository location to what its local location might infer), and `svn info` reveals that it's still mapped to its counterpart. How can I fully resolve this?

**What I've tried**

The difficult thing with svn properties is that they can be set from anywhere. I've tried `svn propedit svn:externals .` from the folder in question, and I've also tried `svn propedit svn:externals {relative-path-to-the-folder}` on all its ancestors, but no dice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-R` parameter of the `svn propget` command to recurse through the entire directory tree: (Note: `pg` is an alias for `propget`)

```
$ svn pg -R svn:externals .
```

This will list all of the directories where `svn:externals` is set. Note that you can do this with the URL too:

```
$ svn pr -R svn:externals http://repo/svn/trunk/proj
```

You can do the same with the `proplist` command and get all of the properties and their values. However, this may be a lot more than you realize -- especially if you have a lot of `svn:mimetype` set because of binary type of files.

```
$ svn pl -R -l .
```

This can be useful for such things as `svn:mergeinfo`, `svn:ignores`, and other types of properties that may have problems.

The `svn:externals` is a powerful tool, but like any powerful tool, you can end up doing a lot of damage. For example, imagine I have this set:

```
 $ svn ps svn:externals http://repo.corp.local/svn/trunk/util util .
```

Let's say I now tag my directory. My `util` directory will still be pointing to trunk and constantly changing which means my tag is changing. If I make a branch, of my project, the `util` directory will be pointing to the trunk and it might end up containing code that is incompatible to my branch.

There are two ways of handling this:

- Always use some revision or tag with your externals directories:

Like this:

```
 $ svn -r$rev ps svn:externals http://repo/svn/trunk/utls@$rev util .
```

which will tie the externals to a specific revision, or:

```
$ svn ps svn:externals http://repo/svn/tags/$tag/util util .
```

which will tie the externals to a specific tag. I like this because the tag usually is more meaningful (although tags can be changed, they're should usually be constant.)

- Or, use relative URLS:

Like this:

```
$ svn ps ../util util .
```

Assuming that your trunk, tags, and branches directory structure is the main level, this will make sure that `util` directory points to the same branch, trunk, or tag as your project. When you branch your project, you need to branch `util` too. When you tag your project, you need to tag `util` too.

Comment: That's a fantastically comprehensive overview of my situation – thanks a lot! My original aim was to alias one directory to another within the same repo, so your last example should be exactly what I need. However A) I was under the impression that external links to within the same repo weren't supported and B) how would you go about separate tags and branches if `utils` is just another folder? For example: I am currently doing all of this on a branch (which I intend to merge back into trunk).